# How to construct a proper sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, adverbs

I read this somewhere: ***It was all too much, it was too scary.*** So my question is, how is this even a correct sentence. It is joining two independent clauses together using a comma. It seems to be ungrammatical. One more example:  ***The people had to resort to foods like the inglorious snail and the frankly sessile nut, their tools show considerable improvement.*** This second one also confuses me. I really struggle with constructing long sentences. Can someone explain to me, and clarify my doubts please!
 I have one more question : ***We had our chance and it came up on one of the house numbers -- double zero, I guess.*** Here also i'm confused. "***I guess***" is written right after a comma."***I guess***" seems to be an independent clause. Is it acting as a modifier? Or is it just an intentional grammar-rule-break from the author. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: It is not a correct sentence as you have noted.  It may be a great place to use a semicolon.  _It was all too much; it was too scary._  Notice I say, "may." The great thing about a semicolon is that it also may not be a good place to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quoted wrongly.  The text, from the Penguin Atlas of Ancient History is:
The mesolithic world is sometimes called impoverished because it lacked the art of the upper palaeolithic and the glamour of the bison chase. But though the largest quarry available were deer and oxen, and mesolithic man, to make ends meet, spent most of his time hunting the inglorious snail and the frankly sessile nut, his tools show considerable progress [...]

---

Punctuation is only tangentially related to grammar insofar as it attempts to reflect phrasal and clausal boundaries.

Authors of stories have license to use punctuation in other ways as well, such as to set the pace of the narrative, or to reflect an agitated mental state, and so forth. This looks to be from a story where such license has been taken:

> It was all too much, it was too scary.

This, however, seems to come from an article, not a work of fiction, and appears to be punctuated incorrectly:

> The people had to resort to foods like the inglorious snail and the frankly sessile nut, their tools show considerable improvement.

Normally there would be a full stop after **nut**:

> The people had to resort to foods like the inglorious snail and the frankly sessile nut. Their tools show considerable improvement.